# Starting Jenkins parameterized build with Jersey REST and JSON parameters

Tags: json, rest, jenkins

I have to start Jenkins parameterized build programmatically using Jersey REST API and the values for the parameters must be provided as a JSON object. Any hint or example is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

So, seems like you have not tried it yourself. I can give you a fast 5 minute solution, that should be reworked to be clear and not so ugly, but it works :)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;


public class JenkinsJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runParamJob("http://jenkins.host/", "SOME_JOB", "{\"object\":\"test\"}");
    }

    public static String runParamJob(String url, String jobName, String paramsJSON) {
        String USERNAME = "user";
        String PASSWORD = "pass";
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.HTTPBasicAuthFilter(USERNAME, PASSWORD));
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url + jobName + "/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=" + paramsJSON);
        ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class, paramsJSON);
        String jsonResponse = response.getEntity(String.class);
        client.destroy();
        System.out.println("Server response:" + jsonResponse);
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stanjer, I tested this example but has two problems: 1. the **get** method accepts only a class parameter and 2. the Jenkins throws the following exeption: **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 88: http://myjenkins:8080/deployment/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER={"param0":"value0"}**. This job has a parameter named param0 and started with value value0 from the dashboard it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use rest API for parameterized build you should use POST and not get according to Jenkins wiki. [Here is](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) an example. Make sure that the json you send is as instructed at the documentation.
take this json for example:
    {"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}

You have two parameters with name and value for each. If I will use what was written at the former answer by @stanjer the json should look like that:
    {"parameter": [{"name":"object", "value":"test"}]}

In addition there is a good discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

I would not recommend to use USER:PASSWORD but use token that could be configured in Jenkins job UI. Here is a class that implements builder pattern for with/without parameters.

```
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.core.util.MultivaluedMapImpl;





public class JenkinsTrigger {


private String host;
private String jenkinsToken;
private String jobParams;
private MultivaluedMap<String,String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
private Client client = Client.create();
private WebResource webResource;

private JenkinsTrigger(JenkinsTriggerBuilder jenkinsTriggerBuilder){
    this.host = jenkinsTriggerBuilder.host;
    this.jenkinsToken = jenkinsTriggerBuilder.jenkinsToken;
    this.jobParams = getJobParams(jenkinsTriggerBuilder.jobParams);
    webResource = client.resource(this.host);
    queryParams.add("token", jenkinsToken);
}

public void trigger(){

    ClientResponse response = webResource.path(this.host).queryParams(queryParams)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
            .header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .post(ClientResponse.class, jobParams);
    if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Job Trigger: " + host);
    }
}

private String getJobParams(Map<String,String> jobParams){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("json={\"parameter\":[");
    jobParams.keySet().forEach(param -> {
        sb.append("{\"name\":\""+param+"\",");
        sb.append("\"value\":\""+ jobParams.get(param) + "\"},");
    });
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    sb.append("]}");
    System.out.println("Job Parameters:" +  sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}


    public static class JenkinsTriggerBuilder {

        private String host;
        private String jenkinsToken;
        private Map<String,String> jobParams = null;

        public JenkinsTriggerBuilder(String host, String jenkinsToken){
            this.host = host;
            this.jenkinsToken = jenkinsToken;
        }

        public JenkinsTriggerBuilder jobParams(Map<String,String> jobParams){
            this.jobParams = jobParams;
            return this;
        }

        public JenkinsTrigger build(){
            return new JenkinsTrigger(this);
        }

    }
}
```

And here is usage sample:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("ENV", "DEV103");
JenkinsTrigger trigger = new JenkinsTriggerBuilder("https://JENKINS_HOST/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters","JOB_TOKEN").jobParams(params).build();
trigger.trigger();
```

best of luck